# C# - Hangman with specified requirements

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a hangman game in C#, but there are many things I have to be aware of. I need to use `StreamReader`, I have to keep the user's records in a file (The name of the user, how many times they attempted to win the game, etc.) and I have to make a menu where the user can either choose a new topic of words, or simply reset the current game.
So what I have so far is the "encryption". The letters of the word is written out with dashes, I can ask the user to choose a name, and to choose a topic. 
But how am I supposed to let the program know when a user finds a letter?
I want it to be like this:
Word: ----- (apple), and if the user types p, a new line comes up, but this time it displays "-pp--". How do I do that?

The code in it's current state:

```
static void wordLength()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\hardi\Desktop\Programozás\gyumolcsok.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2")); 
        string szo = Convert.ToString(sr.ReadLine());

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < szo.Length; i++)  
            {
                Console.Write("_");
            }
        }

    }

    static void userName()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("What's your name? ");
        string user = Console.ReadLine();

    }


    static void category()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number to specify the topic: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Fruit \n2: Animals");
        int caseSwitch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (caseSwitch)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Category: Fruit");
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\hardi\Desktop\Programozás\gyumolcsok.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2"));

                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Category: Animals");
                StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\hardi\Desktop\Programozás\allatok.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2"));

                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("The given number is not an option.");
                return;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 

        userName();
        category();
        wordLength();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: One way would be to keep track of the letters that the user has guessed or has found, and when you write out the '_'s in wordLength() check if the current letter in the hidden word is in the guessed set and if it is then write the letter instead of the _.

Comment: There are many problems with the code that should be fixed before you keep going. For example, you aren't actually storing the user name anywhere. You are instantiating stream readers but never using them (and you might consider using the `File` class to read text files instead of using the `StreamReader` directly). You might consider designing your program flow before you start writing methods, so you know what methods should be created, what their signatures should look like, how program state should be saved, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to treat the word as a char array, and store the guesses that the user has made in another char array. Then, for each character in the word, if it exists in the "guessedLetters" array display it, otherwise display a "-" character.

For example, this method takes a word and a list of characters that the user has guessed, and it displays only the correctly guessed characters:

```
private static string GetMaskedWord(string word, List<char> lettersGuessed)
{
    if (word == null) return word;
    if (lettersGuessed == null) return new string('-', word.Length);

    return string.Join("", word.Select(c => lettersGuessed.Contains(c) ? c : '-'));
}
```

Example usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string word = "apple";

    // This stores the guessed characters, currently only a 'p'
    var guessedLetters = new List<char> {'p'};

    Console.WriteLine(GetMaskedWord(word, guessedLetters));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]